# How to get Unicode input from user in Python?

Tags: python, unicode

this is the code:
`varUnicode = input('\tEnter your Unicode\n\t>') print('\u{}'.format(varUnicode))`
i want to get unicode input from user and print the character. in the above code python gives me an error.

Comment: Please post the error.

Comment: SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \uXXXX escape

Comment: Please provide a full [mcve]. That means the code as a complete code block, as well as the input, desired output, and the full traceback in case of errors.

Comment: Note that ``input`` already provides unicode (actually, generic ``str`` that is a subset of unicode). The ``\u`` escape is a *literal* escape, that is for example ``\u0061`` is a single character – you cannot naively create it via formatting, just as adding the numbers ``1 + 1`` is not the same as the number ``11``. Just ``print(varUnicode)`` should do if you get actual unicode symbols, and ``print(chr(varUnicode))`` if you get unicode ordinals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\u` is an escape sequence recognized in [string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals):

> Escape sequences only recognized in string literals are:
>
> ```
> Escape      Meaning                                  Notes
> Sequence
>
> \N{name}    Character named name
>             in the Unicode database                  (4)
> \uxxxx      Character with 16-bit hex value xxxx     (5)
> \Uxxxxxxxx  Character with 32-bit hex value xxxxxxxx (6)
> ```
>
> Notes:
>
> 4. Changed in version 3.3: Support for name aliases 1 has been added.
> 5. **Exactly four hex digits are required.**
> 6. Any Unicode character can be encoded this way. **Exactly eight hex digits are required.**

Use

```
varUnicode = input('\tEnter your Unicode\n\t>')
print('\\u{}'.format(varUnicode.zfill(4)).encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode('unicode_escape'))
```

or (maybe better)

```
varUnicode = input('\tEnter your Unicode\n\t>')
print('\\U{}'.format(varUnicode.zfill(8)).encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode('unicode_escape'))
```